# Row spacing to group rows based on 1st column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to know how to easily space out the data based on profile_id. Adding a row between each number will help the data look clean for the users. Top picture is what the current data looks like and the bottom picture is what I want it to look like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: VBA is clearly your route here. If you prefer to avoid it, I bet I can come up with a way to do it in a worksheet. Needed clarifications: 1. How many rows of data do you have, roughly? 2. Are the values for [employee_user_id] unique? 3. Do you need to perform this routine once, or is it something you're going to do regularly?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid VBA and your only goal is to visually differentiate each ID number, you can use conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=ISODD($A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's too much to do manually, you can use a simple macro with a loop to check through the column.

Something like

```
Sub ShiftGroups()
Dim lastCell As Variant: lastCell = Range("A2").Value2             
For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 
    If Not cell.Value2 = lastCell And Not cell.Value2 = "" And Not lastCell = "" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Insert
    End If
    lastCell = cell.Value2
Next cell
End Sub
```

This is a pretty basic loop with the added feature that it should skip any already empty rows, so running it several times should be no problem.

IF you are unfamiliar with macros/visual basic, you might need to start with [showing the developer tab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45). And then look up the basics on how to use them.